# How to create array in array using collections and sub collections in Firestore?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create an array of `Categories` that contains `Questions` array.

```
struct CategoryFB {
    var title: String
    var id: Int
    var questions: [QuestionsFB]

    var dictionary: [String : Any] {
        return ["title" : title, 
                "id" : id]
    }
}

extension CategoryFB {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any], questions: [QuestionsFB]) {
        guard let title = dictionary["title"] as? String, let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int else { return nil }

        self.init(title: title, id: id, questions: questions)
    }
}
```

`Firestore` has a following structure

1. Collection("Categories")
2. Document("some_id")
3. Collection("Questions")

How to create array like this?

```
array = [Category(title: "First", 
                  questions: [
                      Question("1"),
                      ...
                  ]), 
         ... ]
```

My try was wrong:

```
db.collection("Categories").order(by: "id", descending: false).getDocuments {
    (querySnapshot, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error when getting data \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print(document.documentID)
            self.db.collection("Categories").document(document.documentID).collection("Questions").getDocuments(completion: { (subQuerySnapshot, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    var questionsArray: [QuestionsFB]?
                    questionsArray = subQuerySnapshot?.documents.compactMap({QuestionsFB(dictionary: $0.data())})
                    self.categoriesArray = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap({CategoryFB(dictionary: $0.data(), questions: questionsArray!)})
                    print(self.categoriesArray![0].questions.count)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you have to create model for Question and second model for Category, and then you have create Question model array in Category model. So when you can create instance of Category model you can access question array by index. Can you please show what question array store?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav To much code .. Can't edit. Question has: title, id, details and some array. I have this model. Now I need to create array of this Objects depends on Category

Comment: You already create Question array in Category model then when you have to append any data in question array of category instance then create question instance and append it in question array

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav I understand this, but can't do it by code. I have like 10 Categories in collection and every category has like 10 documents with collection Questions with 20-40 questions.

Comment: What is in the Questions collection? Just a series of questions in an array? e.g. 0: What is... and 1: Where is...? Can you include a screen shot of the actual structure as it's a bit vague in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution which I found by myself. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

```
func getData(completion: @escaping (_ result: [Any]) -> Void) {
    let rootCollection = db.collection("Categories")

    var data = [Any]()

    rootCollection.order(by: "id", descending: false).getDocuments(completion: {

        (querySnapshot, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error when getting data \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        } else {
            guard let topSnapshot = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }
            for category in topSnapshot {
                rootCollection.document(category.documentID).collection("Questions").getDocuments(completion: {
                    (snapshot, err) in

                    guard let snapshot = snapshot?.documents else { return }

                    var questions = [Question]()

                    for document in snapshot {
                        let title = document.data()["title"] as! String
                        let details = document.data()["details"] as! String
                        let article = document.data()["article"] as! String
                        let link = document.data()["link"] as! String
                        let id = document.data()["id"] as! String
                        let possibleAnswers = document.data()["possibleAnswers"] as! [String]
                        let rightAnswerID = document.data()["rightAnswerID"] as! Int

                        let newQuestion = Question(title: title, article: article, details: details, link: link, possibleAnswers: possibleAnswers, rightAnswerID: rightAnswerID, id: id)

                        questions.append(newQuestion)

                    }
                    let categoryTitle = category.data()["title"] as! String
                    let collectionID = category.data()["id"] as! Int


                    let newCategory = Category(title: categoryTitle, id: collectionID, questions: questions)


                    data.append(newCategory)

                    //Return data on completion
                    completion(data)
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to stem from the fact that you're regenerating your categories array every time you run your subquery, and when you do, you're only supplying a single questions array to the entire thing.

There's lots of ways to fix this. I would probably break it up so that you a) First allow yourself to create a category array without any questions, and then b) Go back through each of your individual subQueries and insert them into your categories as you get them.

Your final code might look something like this. Note that this would mean changing your Category object so that you can first create it without a Questions array, and implementing this custom `addQuestions:toCategory:` method (which would be a whole lot easier if you stored your categories as a dictionary instead of an array)

```
db.collection("Categories").order(by: "id", descending: false).getDocuments {
    (querySnapshot, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Error when getting data \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
    } else {
        self.categoriesArray = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap({CategoryFB(dictionary: $0.data()})
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print(document.documentID)
            self.db.collection("Categories").document(document.documentID).collection("Questions").getDocuments(completion: { (subQuerySnapshot, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    var questionsArray: [QuestionsFB]?
                    questionsArray = subQuerySnapshot?.documents.compactMap({QuestionsFB(dictionary: $0.data())})
                    self.addQuestions(questionsArray toCategory: document.documentID)
                    print(self.categoriesArray![0].questions.count)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately, if you think you're going to be in a situation where you're *always* going to want to grab your questions every time you want to grab a category, you might consider not putting them in a subcollection at all, and just making them a map in the original category document.